# Is the word "encomprise" used in modern English?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, is-it-a-word, dictionaries

If one googles the word **encomprises**, there are 5K+ pages, that have this word. I personally have heard people in the USA use it with a meaning of **include**.

Official dictionaries, on the other hand, only have the word **comprise**.

Is "encomprise" just a verb form of "comprise", making the use of "encomprises" a mistake?

Comment: If enough people keep using it, *encomprise* might eventually become a "word", but IMHO as of now its primary status is evidence of illiteracy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I found 210 results on [Google](http://www.google.com/#q=%22encomprise%22&hl=en&prmd=imvnsb&ei=hggaT8_lI9DTgAeQmOmDDA&start=210&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=f65898e8f69b98a3&biw=897&bih=195), most of which are either duplicates of each other or instances of the word in French.
2. [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=encomprise&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) (Google Books) has no instances.
3. [No online dictionary](http://onelook.com/?w=encomprise&ls=a) that I can find includes *encomprise*.
4. I have never seen the word before.

Therefore, I strongly suspect that it is an eggcorn meaning *[encompass](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/encompass)*, but influenced by *[comprise](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/comprise)*.  *Encomprise* is not an accepted word in modern English.

Comment: You have googled "encomprise". I've got results that are meaningful when googled "encomprises". Most of the results are from a non-english sites, so I can assume this is what non-native speakers, like myself, would logically "make up" for comprise. Still I am positive people in Missouri have used it. Thank you for the answer by the way.

Comment: Encomprise is not in Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary (1913 + 1828 editions). http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?resource=Webster%27s&word=encomprise&float=on&use1913=on&use1828=on

Comment: A common form of this "verb" is [encomprising](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=encomprise+encomprises+encomprised&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&tbo=1&tbs=sbd:1&tbm=bks&source=hp&q=encomprising&pbx=1&oq=encomprising&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=0l0l0l123036l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=c74deb9746404bf2&biw=1270&bih=764) which gets 130 actual results in Google Books, of which a high proportion seem to be by Indian or far Eastern authors. I'm not sure I'd say it's emerging Indian English as such - they're probably just more prone to the error.

Answer (score 0):

The *OED* disavows any knowledge of it. Google is not a dictionary.